# Intercept Tkinter "Exit" command?

Tags: python, client-server, tkinter, exit

I'm writing a client-server program in Python with Tkinter.  I need the server to keep track of the connected clients.  For this, I would like to have the client send an automated message to the server after the exit button(the standard "X" in the corner) is clicked.  How can I know when the user is exiting the program?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I handle the window close event in Tkinter?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111155/how-do-i-handle-the-window-close-event-in-tkinter)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You want to use the [wm_protocol](https://web.archive.org/web/20200731093951id_/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.protocol-method) method of the toplevel window. Specifically, you are interested in the `WM_DELETE_WINDOW` protocol. If you use that method, it allows you to register a callback which is called when the window is being destroyed.

Usage:

```
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", app.on_delete)
```

Comment: So I added this line: `root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", app.on_delete())` right before my call to `root.mainloop()` but `on_delete()` is getting called when the window is *opened* and not when it is closed.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @John: the `protocol` method takes a reference to a function. By adding the trailing parenthesis you are calling `app.on_delete` and passing the result of that method to the protocol handler. The correct usage is `root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", app.on_delete)`

Comment: Setting the protocol like seems to only work with respect to the main window's OS close button, but not, for example, with a Quit button in a `Frame` subclass whose `command=self.quit`). That said, it does answer this question which asks only about the standard exit button.

Comment: @martineau: correct, the protocol only comes into play when the window manager is asked to destroy the window. When you call `quit`, you're just instructing `mainloop` to exit, and the window is destroyed gracefully.

Comment: Bryan: Thanks for the confirmation. I think not understanding the distinction is why more than one of the other answers claim that setting the protocol doesn't work.

Answer (score 7):

You can use python `atexit` module.

For example:

```
import atexit

def doSomethingOnExit():
    pass

atexit.register(doSomethingOnExit)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. The other ones never got triggered.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, the following code didn't work:

```
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", app.on_delete)  # doesn't work
```

However, it worked using this form:

```
root.wm_protocol ("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", app.on_delete)  # does work
```

Comment: There's no answer saying to use `.protocol`, though... the accepted answer already said to use `.wm_protocol`.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare: the accepted answer mentions wm_protocol, but its code snippet uses `.protocol`, not `.wm_protocol`. In any case, both options behave in the exact same way on my machine, I assume piertoni's version differs from mine (unsurprisingly so since the answer dates back to 2012).

Comment: `protocol` and `wm_protocol` are exactly the same function.

Answer (score 2):

FWIW: It is also possible to assign a widget-specific behavior.

If you want an action to occur when a specific widget is destroyed, you may consider overriding the destroy() method. See the following example:

```
class MyButton(Tkinter.Button):
    def destroy(self):
        print "Yo!"
        Tkinter.Button.destroy(self)

root = Tkinter.Tk()

f = Tkinter.Frame(root)
b1 = MyButton(f, text="Do nothing")
b1.pack()
f.pack()

b2 = Tkinter.Button(root, text="f.destroy", command=f.destroy)          
b2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

When the button 'b2' is pressed, the frame 'f' is destroyed, with the child 'b1' and "Yo!" is printed.

I posted the same answer on [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954396/which-method-can-i-override-for-cleanup-task-when-a-tkinter-tk-window-in-python).

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to use a lambda like this:

```
class App:
    def run(self):
        self.root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: self.quit())
    def quit(self):
        self.root.destroy()
```