# Can't copy the value of a Tkinter Entry

Tags: python, tkinter

So i have this code:

```
from Tkinter import *
Admin = Tk()

def searches():
    gett = search.get()
    lab = Label(frame, text='searching for ' + gett)
    lab.pack(side='bottom')
frame = Frame(Admin)
frame.pack()
search = Entry(frame)
search.pack(side='left')

button = Button(frame, text='Search', command=searches)
button.pack(side='right')

getts = search.get()

Admin.mainloop()

other = getts

print other
```

but the "other" doesn't inherit the text in the entry please help.

Comment: `getts` is being assigned the value before `mainloop` (i.e. before your window is even being displayed); assigning `other` to `getts` won't help you. Instead, look into callbacks for an appropriate time to get the value.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `search.get()` and assigning the result to `getts` -- and then assigning that to `other` -- prior to the GUI ever being displayed on the screen. Because of this the result of `search.get()` will be the empty string since you don't pre-load the widget with any data. And because `getts` is empty, when it is assigned to `other`, `other` is empty, too.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting `getts` before the main loop executes. When you run the program and enter something in the Entry field, that doesn't change the value of a variable you've already set.

If you want to read the value of the entry field after `Admin.mainloop()` exits, you'll have to have a Tkinter object set the value of `getts` in response to some GUI action. One way would be with an on-exit callback. See [Intercept Tkinter "Exit" command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643007/intercept-tkinter-exit-command) for example. In your case you want something like

```
Admin.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", SomeFunctionWhichSetsGetts)
```

Or better yet (perusing that linked post further) create a subclass of `Entry` with a `destroy()` method that sets `getts` for you.