# Tkinter: Check if root has been destroyed?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, tkinter

I am writing an application using Tkinter along with threading.

The problem I got is, after closing the main app, some thread is still running, and I need a way to check whether the root windows has been destroyed to avoid the `TclError: can't invoke "wm" command`.

All methods I know: `wminfo_exists()` and `state()` all return error once the root is destroyed.

Comment: Seems like you could put a `try`/`except` around a `wminfo_exists()` call and assume any `TclError` means the root no longer exists.

Comment: test against if tkinter._default_root is not None

Answer (score 11):

I will add my workaround for this, in case anyone came across the same issue. I was following the suggestion from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643007/intercept-tkinter-exit-command). I intercept the windows' closing event to set my flag that marks the `root` is already dead, and check for that flag when I need.

```
exitFlag = False

def thread_method():
    global root, exitFlag
    if not exitFlag:
        // execute the code relate to root

def on_quit():
    global exitFlag
    exitFlag = True
    root.destroy()

root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", on_quit)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using something like this:

```
import Tkinter

root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.bind('<space>', lambda e: root.quit())  # quitting by pressing spacebar
root.mainloop()
```

and not: `root.destroy()` then the quit method will kill the Tcl interpreter not just breaks out from the mainloop and deletes all widgets. So once you called `root.quit()` you can be sure, that your `root` is completely dead!

All the other methods you suggested (like: `wminfo_exists()`) are only available when at least one valid `Tk` exists.

---

***NOTE:***

*If you are using more than one mainloop, you should use the destroy method to make sure, that your **main** mainloop won't be killed -- but I don't think this is your case.*

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem I am having, is that after `root.quit()` I still have some threads running, and I need to let my thread knows that the `root` is already dead. Right now I have to settle with intercepting the quit method and set a global variable to let my thread know that the `root` is dead. I wonder if there would be any other solution.

Comment: `root.winfo_exists()` (without 'm')? anyway, why don't you catch that error with a try/except and when it happens you just kill your thread?

Comment: I was following the [discussion about thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread-in-python) and they mention, it is bad practice to kill a thread during execution. That's why I hope to find a solution that let my program's execution end "peacefully".