# Python session kept open after closing tkinter window with a matplotlib graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I want to put a `matplotlib` figure in a `tkinter` user interface. This is my code, based on the `matplotlib` documentation:

```
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk
import sys

root = tk.Tk()

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4,4))
ax = fig.add_subplot()
line, = ax.plot([1,2,3],[1,4,9])

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
canvas.draw()

toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, root, pack_toolbar=False)
toolbar.update()

canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
toolbar.pack()

tk.Button(root, text="Exit", command=lambda:sys.exit()).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I runs correctly. The problem comes when I close the window. If I press the "X" button of the window, the terminal never finishes, but if I press the "Exit" button I added, it finishes. If instead I use `root.destroy()`, it neither works. How can I solve this issue?

Thanks!

**Edit:**

I uploaded a video in YouTube, so you can see my problem: https://youtu.be/qUkm-lnXRR8

I'm using Windows 11 PowerShell, version:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.1.22621.963
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.22621.963
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Python version 3.11.1

Comment: It shouldn't have that behaviour. How do you run it in the terminal? What OS are you using? Can't reproduce the problem on Ubuntu.

Comment: @TheLizzard see the edit above

Comment: Add a print statement after the `mainloop()`. Does the print statement get called? A temporary work around would be to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4643082/11106801)

Comment: @TheLizzard the print statement after the `mainloop` is never printed. Following the accepted answer on the question you shared, I can use `root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: sys.exit())` and it works. But this cannot be the "final" solution because therefore I cannot run any code after the mainloop is finished.

Comment: instead of `lambda:sys.exit()`, have a function with the code that you want to run after the GUI is closed and make sure the function ends with `sys.exit()`. But that is a work around. For a proper solution, someone needs to look at `matplotlib`'s code and maybe file a bug report.

Comment: Thanks for your comments @TheLizzard , I will report this bug.

Comment: You can track this issue at https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/24874

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/24874), this solves the issue

```
import tkinter as tk
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk
import sys
from matplotlib.figure import Figure #### This is the difference

root = tk.Tk()

fig = Figure() # plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
canvas.draw()

toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, root, pack_toolbar=False)
toolbar.update()

canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
toolbar.pack()

tk.Button(root, text="Exit", command=lambda:sys.exit()).pack()

root.mainloop()

print("Hello")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).